# Is there a macro to validate URLs to check if it page loads or not in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Is there a macro to validate URLs to check if it page loads or not in excel ? I have a list of url in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question several years ago and got this reply:

http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=381186&highlight=jakobshavn

Comment: Link-only answer are a no-no due to possible future link-rot (oh the irony ;) ).  Please include pertinent information in your answer.